# Deeplink no match

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I’am trying to nav with my url on my app, but I did that:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {

  this.deeplinks.route( {

    '/test': AdminPage,

  }).subscribe((match) =>{

    alert("MARCHEEEEE");

    alert(JSON.stringify(match));

  }, (noMatch) =>{
    alert("CA MARCHE PAS TON DEEPLINK");
    alert(JSON.stringify(noMatch));
  });
```

And when I’am doing : http://localhost/#/test it dosent work

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No, just (noMatch)